# Existence of tag in title bar for questions varies, apparently between sites, sometimes between questions

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the first tag sometimes in the <title> tag of some questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions)

I was taking a look at Gaming.SE, and noticed that the first tag from the tag list is being included in the title bar. e.g.:

[image]

Initially, I thought this was a bug with Gaming.SE.  So I checked out BoardGames.SE, which is still in Beta:

[image]

There is no tag here.

I then checked out a different question on BG.SE:

[image]

...which *does* have the tag.

What's the logic behind the feature?

Comment: ...and if it bothers you: [Remove the most popular tag from the title using JavaScript](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71951/remove-the-most-popular-tag-from-the-title-using-javascript/71964#71964).