# Why is the least important tag in the title of this StackExchange page?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

For [this page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26848/how-to-deal-with-project-managers-who-micromanage/26852#26852), the title is

`<title>help - How to deal with project managers who micromanage? - Programmers - Stack Exchange</title>`

where `[help]` is the tag in the title.  The question is tagged `[project-management]` `[help]`.

If this is for [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization), why isn't the `[project-management]` tag (which has 94 questions associated with it) used instead of the `[help]` tag (which only has two questions associated with it)?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72063/ , http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/ (I should know, the first of those was *my* question :p)

Comment: @Margaret: OK, but this is not the first tag, it is the second one. Since tags are sorted by popularity, getting the second tag is going to get the less important one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some cases where less important tags will be included in tag titles.

Note that on that question the *most important* tag is [project-management], which essentially already appears as "project managers" in the title.  Including "project management" in the title would be redundant for SEO purposes.

Comment: Ah, I see.  That makes sense.  SEO seems so arbitrary sometimes.

Comment: @robert the root problem is that "help" is a meaningless tag and should be removed