# The [help] tag needs somebody

Tags: support, tags, tag-block-request

...but not just *anybody*.

My keen intuition and flawless deductive skills have informed me that this is [not a very good tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80288/burninate-the-help-tag). There're 15 questions on SO with the [help](/questions/tagged/help) tag right now, of which only three seem to be legitimate uses.

What ought a humble vigilante janitor do in cases like this? Retag the invalid ones manually? Retag the valid ones to something else and wait for the offending tag to meet an incandescent demise, that we might dance around its funeral pyre?

**Edit**: Looks like [someone helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23897/michael-petrotta) has started cleaning up manually. Still wondering about the situation involving bad tags being blacklisted though...

Comment: It simply must be cleaned up again.  [Check out the old post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80288/burninate-the-help-tag).

Comment: @M. Tibbits: I was under the impression that bad tags were killed and couldn't be recreated. I guess this one was only mostly dead...

Comment: The [tag:help]'s not dead yet? It will be soon...  But [tag:help] says it's not dead?!?

Comment: FYI: I too thought it was to be blacklisted -- [see Jeff's comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72377/why-is-the-least-important-tag-in-the-title-of-this-stackexchange-page#comment-174739)

Comment: @M. Tibbits: Yep. That's why I decided to make the post here rather than just quietly clean up the mess. :?

Comment: Deleting the tag is not the same thing as blacklisting it.  The same thing recently happened with [the error tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97187/the-error-tag-has-come-back-to-life), which has now been both burninated and blacklisted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I scrubbed that tag from all but three questions (and did a bunch of edits to all fifteen). I'd suggest to other "vigilantes" out there, that when the numbers are so modest, just do the same.

As far as blacklisting the tag, I dunno... 20% of questions appear to be using the tag properly. But maybe that's too low to justify its existence.

Comment: I saw! Good show. Your dedication to improving SO is an example to us all.

Comment: It's (abused as) a pure meta tag, therefore there is *no* question using the tag "properly."

Comment: @Charles, did you look at the questions using that tag?

Comment: @Charles: The ones using it properly are about "help" features in applications, help files, or related topics.

Comment: @Michael, there are better terms that can be used for those specific questions than just "help."  Two of them are about CHM, the other about Apple Help files.  Creating specific tags just for those and banning the "help" tag will prevent it from being misused by the typical new user that doesn't understand how tags work.

Comment: @Charles, quite possibly. That's different than saying that there's no proper use for that tag.

Comment: If people can't use it correctly even *half* the time, I'd be inclined to favor burnination. I mean, really.

Comment: I've retagged the [three](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6661411) [remaining](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6714933) [legitimate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6675963) uses, and the [one misuse](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6716232) that had already cropped up. Burninate it!