# Please blacklist the [help] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-block-request, meta-tags

It's previously been [burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80288/burninate-the-help-tag), and has been [edited out of existence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98737/the-help-tag-needs-somebody) more than a few times by more than a few people, myself included.  But it keeps coming back.

While there is a case for having [help](/questions/tagged/help) exist for the purpose of discussing *help files*, the common case seems to be users *asking* for help, which makes it a meta tag of the worst sort.  There are other tags to discuss the creation and management of *help files* that aren't so poorly named.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, if we removed it and it keeps coming back, that's a fair argument for blacklist. Consider it added.