# Why is "javascript" in the <title> tag of my C# question?

Tags: discussion, tags

This was a C# question, through and through:

[How do I do division on HH:MM:SS format time strings in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663008/how-do-i-do-division-on-hhmmss-format-time-strings-in-c)
It mentions a JavaScript solution, but only as an aside to the main question. Still, I felt it was relevant enough to add a JavaScript tag.

After reading [Remove the most popular tag from the title using JavaScript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71951/remove-the-most-popular-tag-from-the-title-using-javascript)
 and [Does the order of keywords matter in a page title?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/does-the-order-of-keywords-matter-in-a-page-title) I see **it's somehow meant to combat scrapers, but to a relatively new SE user like myself, it doesn't look right. It looks like a bug.**

---

Edit:

If I remove C# from the title, the article's prefix will become "C# - " because C# is the most popular of all tags I'm using. But then the on-page title becomes ambiguous: "How do I do division on HH:MM:SS format time strings?" Users will look at the tags and not know if it's a Javascript or a C# question.

> So just delete the Javascript tag, man!

I know, I know. I suppose I don't *need* the Javascript tag in there. But isn't Javascript a relevant part of the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You tagged the question [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), and since C# is already mentioned in the title that tag is ingored and the next most popular tag (javascript in this case) is prefixed to the title. You can fix this by either removing the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag or removing "in C#" from the title.

Regarding your edit, make it clear this is a C# question in the question's body.

Comment: Is that to say if I hadn't had "C#" in the title, would the article be prefixed with C#?

Comment: @Jake Yes, but only because C# is a more common tag than JavaScript. If you had a JavaScript question also tagged C#, then it would be labelled C# in the title regardless.