# Would it be better for SEO to add multiple tags for a question title?

Tags: discussion

The title of a question seems to take the first tag from its tag list, for example:

[What is the best game type to level up in?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33491/bf3-what-is-the-best-game-type-to-level-up-in)

The full title is  `xbox 360 - BF3 What's the best....`

If the author hadn't put BF3 in the title the question could have been for any game, from a search engine's perspective. Would it be a good idea to take the first two tags or maybe advise people on the order that tags should appear is important?

Or alternatively have people edit titles to include the game name. This probably extends to other sites beyond the gaming one, I'm just using that as an example.

Comment: Related: [Remove the most popular tag from the title using JavaScript](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71951/remove-the-most-popular-tag-from-the-title-using-javascript) [Why is the first tag sometimes in the <title> tag of some questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/) [Why is “javascript” in the <title> tag of my C# question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75821/why-is-javascript-in-the-title-tag-of-my-c-question) [Which tag is added to the page title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/)

Comment: It's a little bit ironic, though, many people have tried to get rid of these tags in the title, you suggest to put more in. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much a Gaming specific problem, on most sites the most used tag is usually the right one to put into the title. On Gaming this is very often not the case, there you *always* want the game tag to be added to the title.

[There is a feature request on Gaming Meta to help with that](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2266/allow-tags-to-be-blacklisted-specifically-from-appearing-in-the-html-page-title), this specific requests asks for a blacklist of tags that should never appear in the title. This would be the easiest way, though Gaming could really use a way to differentiate game tags from other tags.

If you can organically edit in the game name into the title, you can do that. This is pretty much the current workaround.