# The new {TagName} - {This is the real title} formatting is unhelpful

Tags: discussion, sorting, title

One of the best things SO did IMHO was to correctly order the HTML title in the order:

> {Question Title} - {SiteName}

This was great because we knew the site name (and the favicon is a better indicator once you recognize it), it was the question that was important.

Especially now, that browsers have almost all truncated the title into *only* the tab title of a webpage the first 20 characters are the critical ones to define a page.

However I now see that questions are titled as:

> {Random TagName} - {Question Title} - {SiteName}

Thus when I look at a bunch of tabs I have open now I see:

"javascript - runni..."
"project hosting - ..."
"version control - ..."
"javascript - How t..."

All of which are pretty useless as descriptions for which question is which.

**Update:** here's a screenshot showing how useless the titles now are:

[image: Now which tab was the HTML5 video question?]

***Now which tab was the HTML5 video question?*** (hint its the 8th tab)

If you'd still like to keep a tag name in the title that's ok, but the hierarchy of the title should go from small/finite to biggest/general, thus in this order.

> Item - Category - Site
>
> {Question Title} - {Random TagName} - {SiteName}

Is there any chance we can get the order of labels in the title corrected?

Comment: The order is determined by SEO. Sites that were taking SO content and republishing it were appearing higher up the search rankings. This change corrected that.

Comment: So to do a quick optimization for SEO we've decided to throw the baby out with the bath water and wreck the actual user experience for those that use the site?! - I'd like to believe that Google will always correct **its** ranking behavior to put SO on top as they are well aware of where the content is really coming from.

Comment: You'll have to wait for a response from Jeff or one of the devs. I'm just a user.

Comment: Related: [Remove the most popular tag from the title using JavaScript](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71951/remove-the-most-popular-tag-from-the-title-using-javascript)

Comment: See here: [First tag in the title of the page is not that convenient.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71906/first-tag-in-the-title-of-the-page-is-not-that-convenient)

Comment: @ChrisF, are the reasons to insert tag for SEO still relevant? SEO algorithms changed for 6 years.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim - I'd have to refer you to my previous comment. I'm just a user.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, we can't change this without materially harming the network.

You might try a few things:

1. Configure your browser to make the tabs twice as wide by default. I find most modern browsers have absurdly small default tab sizes for some reason.
2. Try Arjan's suggestion of
   [Remove the most popular tag from the title using JavaScript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71951/remove-the-most-popular-tag-from-the-title-using-javascript)
   ( this might need to be on http://stackapps.com )

Comment: :-) I actually linked to a feature request. But the user script in one of the answers might indeed work well too!

Comment: so reordering the tag to the correct heirarchical position will break SEO? This seems very odd.

Comment: @scunliffe Aye, putting the tag in the front is what benefits the SEO. [See here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/does-the-order-of-keywords-matter-in-a-page-title), in particular HTG and Jeff's comment exchange on the accepted answer, as one of many elements in a hefty discussion on the subject.

Comment: I take it that we also raised an issue with Google that they may want to tweak their algo to avoid spammer sites from gaming Google!

Comment: Are the reasons to insert tag for SEO still relevant? SEO algorithms changed for 6 years.