# Remove tags from page titles

Tags: feature-request, tags, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we stop adding the most popular tag to the HTML title on every SE site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127370/should-we-stop-adding-the-most-popular-tag-to-the-html-title-on-every-se-site)

I do not think tags should be included in page titles. Currently, page titles are in the form `tag - Question Title`. I think the tags should be omitted because it can make it difficult to  tell which question is which if you have more than one question with the same tag open at once.

[image: Tabs in Google Chrome with tags in Stack Overflow page titles]

In this image, I have the Newest Questions page on the left, and four questions tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) on the right. Can you tell which questions are open? I certainly can't; all I see is C++ and part of the first letter. This is even worse with long tags.

[image: Tabs in Google Chrome with tags in Math.SE page titles]

Tags are good for organizing questions, but they do not make good page titles.

Comment: Page titles figure heavily into search rankings.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Could they be put at the end of the title instead?

Comment: That is a good suggestion. In my opinion, tags should be moved to the end.

Comment: No, putting important keywords closer to the beginning of a title helps SEO.  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/6556/3922

Comment: They're also a direct response to sites "stealing" SO content without attribution. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions/71925#71925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, tags are added to the beginning of the page title for good reason.  Putting important keywords closer to the beginning of an HTML title helps SEO.  See the discussion on the Webmasters question [Does the order of keywords matter in a page title?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/6556/3922)

Comment: How do we decide which tag to put in the title? It is often one of the least relevant tags that is added.

Comment: @ctype.h It's always the most popular tag, unless that's already worked into the title.

Comment: Is it possible to have them **not** displayed locally via a user preference ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D No, but it's always "tag - title" so you could probably write a userscript to strip it out.  See [How to make Stack Exchange behave exactly how you want it to](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/07/how-to-make-stack-exchange-behave-exactly-how-you-want-it-to/?cb=1).

Comment: Thanks ! I would maybe start a discussion for such a pref -  I would personally need it