# Let's not put tag name before the question's title in browser title

Tags: discussion, tags, title, browsers

I've missed the moment when we've started to put tag name first in the webpage title (or the fact that it was the case since the very beginning), however to me this seems to be a very, well, how it is politely said, sub-optimal decision. The actual title of the question **is always more informative than any tag attached to it**. Also, as a person who deals with a lot of posts simultaneously - it makes it harder to navigate through multiple tabs.

[image]

Tabs for seven different items about ImageMagic are indistinguishable:

[image: Multiple tabs all say the same thing.]

So I want to propose not to put tag name before the question title in the browser title.

Comment: At least tags are short and if they are not informative then the tag is wrong.

Comment: @rene they are not always short and I've never claimed they are not informative - however the title of the question is always more relevant than any tag attached.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127370/should-we-stop-adding-the-most-popular-tag-to-the-html-title-on-every-se-site as well as: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180100/titles-should-be-stand-alone-summaries-of-questions-without-depending-on-tags

Comment: It's interesting that for this item itself, and for meta.SE in general, the tags do not appear in the title.

Answer (score 5):

I don't use the tab title, so I'm not bothered by your examples. What does bother me though is that tags often chew up valuable space in Google results instead of showing more of the title:

- "proper nouns - Why are the United States often referred to as ..."
- "legislative process - How would the United States of America grant ..."
- "marvel cinematic universe - Which prior MCU films are specifically ..."
- "marvel cinematic universe - How accurate to the comics is the Iron ..."

Interestingly enough, Google sometimes strips out the tag, or at least that's what I'm seeing for Stack Overflow titles:

- "How to sort an array of integers correctly - Stack Overflow"
- "How to sort an array based on the length of each element? - Stack ..."
- "Sort array of objects by string property value - Stack Overflow"
- "How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields? - Stack Overflow"

(I actually liked seeing Stack Overflow tags in Google results, since it was almost always the language tag and the language is pretty important.)

Shog's [response to this request in 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127422/323179) was that you should work the tags into the title of the question if you don't want them prepended (which is why the title of this very question is pretty funny) or choose your tags better. However, this isn't a good solution because:

- It's not obvious that titles work this way.
- Why would I edit a title/tags to do this? It's not a good use of anyone's time, nor is it worth bumping the question over.
- Have you seen how long tags have gotten? The max is now 35 characters per tag everywhere and many questions require several tags: on Science Fiction and Fantasy, [avengers-endgame] needs to be used with [marvel-cinematic-universe] and [marvel]. There is no elegant way to put all of these in a title.