# Capitalise tag name correctly when inserting into page title

Tags: feature-request, tags, title

Given the recent change to insert the "main" tag in the page title for SEO purposes ([Why is the first tag sometimes in the  tag of some questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions)), I think the page title would look a lot better if the tag was in the correct case (eg `ASP.NET` instead of `asp.net`).  The lower-case presentation in the page has always been OK given the way it's styled, but I find it really grating in the title.

It should be really easy to implement - update the TagName in the tag table (there aren't **that** many where it's a "big" issue), and add `text-transform: lowercase;` to the tag CSS.

Comment: Are you saying that tags are stored using the correct case? If not, then as for `JAVASCRIPT` and `WEB-DEVELOPMENT` versus `javascript` and `web-development`, I prefer the latter.

Comment: @Arjan as I understand it (and according to the data explorer), they are all currently stored - and therefore presented - in lower case.  I am proposing that where the proper name for a tag includes capital letters, such as ASP.NET, that tag could be updated in the tag table so that when it's put into the start of the page title, it appears as ASP.NET.  You can use CSS to maintain the existing lower case presentation in the page.  Not proposing that everything would be switched to upper case.

Comment: Ah, @Jon, I missed your "update the TagName in the tag table"; my bad!

Comment: Keep in mind, this isn't going to be a one-time fix. Users who are going to be creating tags are primarily going to see them in their lowercase version, which is going to incline them to create them in this lowercase fashion. While this is not likely to be a "big" issue, it is going to require monitoring for whenever those cases do turn up.

Comment: And what about tags which aren't proper nouns? Their canonical form should be all lower case, but in the page title, you'll probably want them in title case.