# Allow tag wiki editors to specify the preferred capitalization/punctuation of a tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

[image: The tag "javascript" at the beginning of the title becomes capitalized to show the difference.]

It is ridiculous that since we prefixed tag names to our page titles, the title no longer begins with a capital letter as it should according to the grammar of the English language. Tag badges differ from "normal" badges in this way as well.

[image: The proposed capitalization change in tag badges]

Tag wiki editors should be able to specify the preferred capitalization/punctuation of a tag when it is shown in such places as page titles. It need not affect the display of the tag listing for a question, just specific places such as the title bar and the names of tag badges.

If it is a concern, we could restrict such changes to those of capitalization or punctuation. That is, the new title, with spaces replaced by hyphens, should normalize to the usual tag name.

Comment: "according to the grammar of the English language" - I suspect you'll have to come up with a significantly better reason to make this change, as it's not a small, simple change, and the SO style has always been to use lowercase.

Comment: ...nor is "JavaScript" according to English capitalization guidelines (Scottish, perhaps).

Comment: You spelled capitalisation wrong

Comment: @random: Not according to American usage

Comment: I don't think this would be such a huge change at all (as in it would take very little time to implement) - but could result in a tidier looking site, attracting more Google users, etc to our site.

Comment: @fluteflute: It's always simple and quick when somebody *else* has to do the work.  And the comment about attracting more Google users is preposterous - what possible effect could the capitalization of tags have on that?

Comment: I suggested this 3 weeks ago :P http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72107/capitalise-tag-name-correctly-when-inserting-into-page-title

Answer (score 3):

The all-lowercase, all-the-time approach to tags makes for some uncomfortable reading, especially in cross-linked tag wikis. For example, consider this excerpt from the [web-applications](/questions/tagged/web-applications) wiki:

> A web application is a client-server application that bases the communication on the [http](/questions/tagged/http) protocol. Often a third layer implements data persistence through a database.
>
> The client side runs in a web browser that sends the http requests, receives the responses, renders the response's content (usually a [html](/questions/tagged/html) page, but also video streams, or applets).

According to [commonly practice regarding acronyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym#Case), 'http' in the second paragraph should be corrected to 'HTTP'. However, doing so would make the tags appear wrong (despite what the texters think, "lol").

In order to improve the appearance and professionalism of the tag wikis, and indeed other places where tags are used, I support the request to allow the use of proper capitalization in tags.