# Why are tag names case insensitive?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I think tag names should be case sensitive since for certain names, such as JavaScript and not javascript adds additional value. That is, the Camel notation nomenclature.

Comment: So you want to introduce case sensitive synonyms?

Comment: I tried to do a tag synonym edit and I got error message saying that it doesn't make sense in suggesting the same name as synonym.

Comment: "adds additional value" -- how, exactly?

Comment: @balpha: Actually I meant to say, it feels better. I guess it's not that important and would result in more issues than benefit.

Comment: @Gunner: Ah okay. Yeah, once you start with camelCase, people want spaces (it's called "feature request", not "feature-request"), we have edit wars over capitalization of tags, etc. etc. :) They way it currently is, at least everybody is on the same page.

Comment: @balpha Personally, I've always wondered why we use hyphens instead of underscores, but I'm pretty sure there's a Meta question that I just haven't found on the subject.

Comment: I *think* this feature request is about is having tags be displayed with proper capitalization, *not* about making tag searches case-sensitive. Big difference. Is this correct?

Comment: @Jon: You are absolutely correct. This is what I was getting at.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72107/capitalise-tag-name-correctly-when-inserting-into-page-title

Comment: I probably should have said this earlier: it may be a good idea to rewrite your post to clarify, since people seem to have gotten the wrong impression.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Case insensitivity makes it easier on the tagging system. When you see "javascript" as a tag, you can probably immediately tell it's referring to JavaScript. The difference is, between you who is experienced with the language and someone who is new to programming, only you will know the correct capitalization.

By not requiring capitalization, we don't add an extra level of difficulty in knowing how to describe the problem you're having. We already face quite a few misspellings in tags. We cut this down significantly so that we don't have Javascript, JavaScript, and javascript all intending to mean the same concept.

Comment: Ok, I understood your point.

Answer (score -2):

**Update**: I have now settled down with **all lowercase tag names**.

### Camel case is too 'heavy' for tag names; especially if many are put together.

***Following is my old view that has since changed:***

> I suggest that tag names should remain case-insensitive but should be displayed with proper casing i.e. camel case.
>
> Thus javascript and JavaScript should be the same to the tagging system but should be displayed with proper camel case.
>
> At minimum: I suggest- there be a user specific option to choose how it's displayed per user according to his preference.

Comment: I don't understand why there's so much resentment to this issue. I manage to get downvoted even when i only speak of per-user preference that does not affect other users.

Comment: It's not that you're doing something wrong. Here, on Meta, downvotes simply reflect disagreement of the community with your opinion, not the quality of the post. You didn't get these votes out of resentment.