# Explicitly set tag wiki title to gussy it up for the stage, page

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki, title

Tag wikis have no idea how to properly write the tag they're writing about. So let human fleshbot editors explicitly set this in order for the `<title>` of the page to dress up something fine to its nines.

Currently, for a globulus tag such as [e-commerce](/questions/tagged/e-commerce) you can guess that the real spelling is either one of the following:

- e commerce
- e-commerce

One of these is wrong.

The page title also just shows thusly:

> 'e-commerce' tag wiki - Stack Overflow

These tag gazeteers and almanacs need to allow for a prettier dash of eyelashes and have a field to control how the title is shown.

Then you could have something fine like any of the following:

- JavaScript instead of javascript
- SQL Server instead of sql-server
- OCaml instead of ocaml

This will make the tag repos look more like they're touched in their special places by fellow humans than being probed and set up on the gurney by robots.

Then the current heading on the tag wiki could swap out

> About [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

into a more bedazzled:

> About jQuery

and the HTML title would be something more gold-toothed like:

> jQuery tag reference - Stack Overflow

But let's not be too far reaching about this and see some kind of spillover of case sensitivity showing up in [how they display as tags in questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83724/why-are-tag-names-case-insensitive).

(Coked up SEO gurus will probably tell you that "reference" is more searched than "wiki" between lines on the mirror.)

Comment: this is essentially what I was on about here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72107/capitalise-tag-name-correctly-when-inserting-into-page-title - although I think it was before tag wikis

Comment: Could be done with: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302350/should-we-keep-the-friendly-tag-name-feature