# Which tag is added to the page title?

Tags: discussion, tags, title, window-title

Over at [Why is the first tag sometimes in the <title> tag of some questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71922/133693), [Rebecca](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140548/rebecca-chernoff) [mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions/71925#71925)

> To this end, the tag listed first on a question (**sorted by popularity of the tag**)

So, what's the basis for tag popularity? Views? It sure as hell isn't number of questions.

---

[image]

[image]

---

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As Jeff mentions in his answer on that question, the implementation appears to have changed since then.  To make a guess, I believe that they now look at the top 2 tags on a question.  In your example, `Windows 7` is included in the title, so it isn't prepended as a tag.  It moves on to the next tag.  I wonder what happened if you edited the title to say `64 bit` rather than `64-bit`.  My guess is that the tag then wouldn't be prepended.

On the WebApps question, *google chrome* is contained within the question, though not as a phrase, so it is omitted, and the logic moves on to the next tag.  Firefox isn't in the title so it includes that.

Again, just a guess from observation.

Comment: But then, `[windows-7]` should've been the obvious title-tag, right ? How come it isn't ?

Comment: @Sathya, because [windows-7] is parsed out to `windows 7` which is already in your title.  The code logic doesn't duplicate a tag that is already in your title.

Comment: Makes sense. @Rebecca.

Comment: A discussion came up today in chat over what tags should go on the [branch predictor question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array). Would it make sense to allow some manual control over what tag is appended to the title. Putting [tag:branch-prediction] into the title would greatly increase the search engine visibility of that question. But it doesn't feel right to edit the actual title of the question since that essentially changes the question itself.