# What determines a question page's (document) title?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tag is added to the page title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/which-tag-is-added-to-the-page-title)

Hi guys.

I was just having a look at [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661817/php-calculate-float-help). My attention was drawn to the what appeared in my Chrome tab's title, which was:

> math - php calculate float HELP!! -
>   Stack Overflow

Upon a detailed investigation, which involved right-clicking and selecting 'view page source' from the page's context menu, I saw the following, which makes perfect sense, of course:

```
<title>math - php calculate float HELP!! - Stack Overflow</title>
```

It caught my attention because the question has these tags (in order):

> PHP math floating-point calculate

So, my question is, what algorithmic awesomeness decided that the 'math' tag should be prepended to the document's title, and that it should precede the question's other tags, to become the 'dominant' subject of the document's title?

Comment: @Rebecca Chernoff - That seems to answer it. Thanks. Post that as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: @karim79, your question will be closed as a duplicate of that.  If the other question and answer is helpful to you, then you can upvote those to indicate that.  (Hover over the up arrow and read the tooltip.)

Comment: @Rebecca - I agree, on some level, but at the same time I think this might be *productive* duplication, in that it might help out the next shmoe who can't find it :) of course, the community decides.

Comment: Even if closed as a duplicate, it won't be deleted.  It will stick around with a link to the original question so that people still get their answer.  This makes it unnecessary to duplicate the answers.

Comment: I was wondering the same and for what it's worth, I don't like this new "feature" but can live with that. :)