# Automatic selection of question's main tag

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tag is added to the page title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/which-tag-is-added-to-the-page-title)

**Can someone please explain how the system about selecting main tag of question currently works?**

Because

- My questions tagged by not popular tags, are not prefixed with any tag
- Some of my questions, are tagged with (afaik) most strong tag from all assigned tags
- Some are just tagged with first tag I wrote

And the situation confuses me a little bit.