# What determines which tag is displayed as part of a question when multiple tags are present?

Tags: support, tags

When posting questions to several different sites across the Stack Exchange network, I've noticed that depending on the tags that I've included as part of my question, one of these tags will sometimes be selected and added to the title of the question. As an example, if you take a look at a question that I posted on the Apple Stack Exchange site ([In countries where the Emergency Services can be called without a SIM card, what caller ID is shown to them when called from an iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377045/in-countries-where-the-emergency-services-can-be-called-without-a-sim-card-what)), you'll notice that the "Cellular Carriers" tag is listed in the title of the page - despite it being the second tag listed as part of the question. What determines which tag is shown as part of the title of the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which tag is added to the page title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/which-tag-is-added-to-the-page-title)