# Can I see what search terms are most often used to get to stackoverflow?

Tags: support, search, google

I saw this page http://www.101appsblog.com/alternativa-pc-game/

and it has footer saying

```
Incoming search terms:

alternativa walkthrough
alternativa game walkthrough
```

Does stackoverflow has statistics like this?

Comment: The one thing I see missing from your question is a reasonable explanation of why you might need that information, what you would plan to do with it. I can understand being curious, but that seems like the sort of thing they wouldn't want to reveal to just everyone, cf http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922

Comment: The link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get some sort of non-authoritative analytics on [alexa](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com#) (click "Search analytics").

They are estimated, but should at least be somewhat accurate.

For Stack Overflow they would be:

1. stack overflow  0.18%
2. jquery redirect 0.04%
3. stackoverflow   0.04%
4. jquery this     0.03%
5. php self    0.03%
6. jquery create element   0.03%
7. jquery timeout  0.02%
8. jquery settimeout   0.02%
9. call javascript in jquery   0.02%
10. nib file with two view  0.02%

Comment: How does Alexa get those figures?

Comment: @Hippo the same way they get rankings: from users that use their toolbar. Since it's the biggest website of its kind there is a considerable number of users using it, and since stackoverflow is also popular, it makes the data fairly accurate.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, not publicly, no. IIRC, moderators have guest access to SO's Google Analytics account, which contains such information. But it's not open to the public.