# Applying custom moderator tags to questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, moderator-tools

We are discussing possible ways in order to [make Code Review more useful for external users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/444/2254). Right now code is reviewed and that's it, the question/answer is no longer useful for anyone else. One of the ideas that popped up was to apply specific tags to questions in order to categorize them as examples of design principles or bad practices.

We were wondering whether it would be possible to use custom tags similar to moderator tags on meta for this. The system already implements something similar to allow some tags to be red. Obviously it would be more complicated than 'just moving the feature over to main', but it doesn't seem unfeasible, and it could be a nice feature across the network.

Comment: Ignoring that they might be somewhat iffy tags, why do they need to be mod-only?  Regular users who can evaluate whether other tags are appropriate should equally be able to evaluate questions for these tags.

Comment: @MatthewRead: It would involve a custom process where questions get 'elected' to be proper example questions. Using the tagging system for this would create a more accessible resource than just listing them in e.g. a meta post.

Comment: @MatthewRead: You could compare it to votes required to close a question. It's actually pretty similar. A consensus needs to be built first before making the decision.

Comment: And before you downvote us to oblivion, let me remind everyone that Code Review is a [bit experimental](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165/is-code-review-useful-for-external-users/168#168). We are exploring creative ways to make it a better place.

Comment: Right.  Well, changes to how tags work are general ill-received, especially when they're not consistent with how tags are designed to work (see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119796/154510), so: Good luck!

Comment: @MatthewRead: Still makes it a worthwhile experiment to consider possible shortcomings of the SE system and see where it can be improved. ;p

Comment: @MatthewRead That was my concern as well, and I tried to convince Steven that [it won't work](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/445/4673). That said, we are nothing if not adventurous...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need more moderator tags for this to work, and I wouldn't support such a scheme anyway as it would be IMO, too complex.

Generally users don't "fight" retagging their questions, so it'd be easiest and simplest to just experiment with retagging rather than proposing some broad change to the engine.

Comment: Is it a broad change to the engine? We have mod only red tags on metas, the mechanics are there...

Comment: Agreed, I feel it could work with simple re tagging as well, but I don't see the 'added complexity' to the scheme about moderator only tags at all. It's just an added security to solve the issue [you raised on Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/445/2254): _"However you would have to be disciplined about making sure the tags are indeed principles and not judgments about the code."_.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could make regular tags work if you make the [retag questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions) privilege require 20k reputation points on Code Review. (Or any other similarly high number where someone could be trusted to Do The Right Thing. For such a new site, perhaps 10k or 5k is more appropriate.) Any user can propose re-tagging and the tag requests would enter the suggested edits queue where two users could confirm or reject the modification.

Moderators might still be needed to fix the cases when two out of the first three people to review a retag request get it wrong -- but the community remains involved.

Comment: +1 Nice 'thinking outside of the box' idea! However, this wouldn't prevent the OP from applying those tags would it?

Comment: Ah, I think you're right, it probably would require another change to the permissions to also require the retag privilege when the user edits their own question, which does remove some of the simplicity of my proposal.