# Why is placing the tag name in the question title bad?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, title, google

I often see edits which remove tags like "C#", "SQL", etc. from question titles. Why are tags in titles considered bad practice?

It doesn't make things unclear; it doesn't confuse anybody. But, most importantly, **this enables search engines to find relevant posts** much easier, especially if some concept or technology is present in different languages.

Comment: I would be staggered if search engines didn't search the tags

Comment: Actually the tags appear in search engines text. [See this google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=What%27s+the+difference+between+String+and+string%3F&oq=What%27s+the+difference+between+String+and+string%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.527j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) check the name of the first result as it appears on google, then click through and see how it appears on StackOverflow.

Comment: They do, but often words that are near each other means a lot more for the engine than just some tag for a page

Comment: you can try searching any tag name in google with restriction to stackoverflow site and you'll see that top-links all contain tag in the title. So it is considered more relevant by Google

Comment: Also: ["Using" Tags in the Title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211267/188759)

Comment: Tag names are automatically prepended to the page title for SEO purposes (edit: ah, not anymore apparently. SO are doing just fine SEO-wise though.)

Comment: For example [this search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+spring+checkstyle+findbugs+pmd&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=UkThUtXOMejH7AaS94HwBg) (in which I only searched for tags) shows the question I was looking for on the third entry down. It *looks* like the OP appended java at the front, but they didn't. In fact only one of the 5 tags is in the title, (some others in the main body - naturally)

Comment: Yeah, they are already optimizing for this somehow, by some formula.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Looks like I made not enough investigation before asking. My search with C# returned all questions with "C#" in the question title.

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy [First page of a search for "C# site:stackoverflow.com", no C# in title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string)

Comment: @Pëkka the most popular tag is prepended to the page title, if it isn't included in the question title already.

Answer (score 18):

Titles are primarily for humans. SO is doing just fine on Google juice and the algorithms don't need your help. So write for people. That means that

```
SQL, C#: find top 3 sales reps
```

is a crappy title but

```
Why doesn't this SQL query correctly return the top 3 sales reps?
```

is a better one. It's not *"don't use tag words in titles"* it's *"don't stick tag words artificially at the beginning or end of titles in the belief you're making your question more findable - you're not."*

Answer (score 7):

The main tag is appended to the title for Google searches (by being added into the title element), so it doesn't need to be added to the title.

[image: Google Tag Append]

[Ultimate Team Reference Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71925/13295)
[Reference 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184273/13295)
[Reference 3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119796/13295)
[Reference 4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127370/13295)