# Questioning the removal for a tag on my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, title

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21358576/revisions

I created a tag to indicate that problem referred to Microsoft's hosteed TFS (Visual studio online) and not to a standard 'in house hosted TFS'.

But people seem to want to remove it. I wonder if there is any reasoning behind this that I'm missing.

Comment: I removed the tag from your title, but I agree with you that [tag:visual-studio-online] belongs in the tags.

Answer (score 2):

You are welcome to put this information in the body of your post, or to use a tag. But tags don't belong in titles. At least not artificially like that. See [Why is placing the tag name in the question title bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217234/why-is-placing-the-tag-name-in-the-question-title-bad/217236#217236)

Comment: True, but I thought they were referring to revision 4, not revision 6.

Comment: @icktoofay - I was but, this is good answer that's educated me!