# Questions with "Topic:" in title

Tags: discussion, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

It seems to me that it would be good to mark title of the question with some general topic first... For example this question: [***Android:*** How to get an icon associated with specific Account from AccountManager.getAccounts()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10657096/1048087)

The main topic ("**Android**") of the question is very visible. But when I write some other questions in same style they are often edited by the community. For example, this question: [How can I combine values from one column into one row?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11505711/1048087) initially had this title: "***SQLite:*** How can I combine values from one column into one row?".

Why was "SQLite:" removed from the title by the community?

Comment: This is [discussed in the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/167443).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to add the subject to the question title.  That's what tags are for.  Don't put `SQLite` in the title, tag it `SQLite`.

Note: The page title will already show the 1st tag before the question title.

Comment: Though to be clear, it's not *always* a bad idea to omit things that are in tags from the title of the question.  But when it's of the form "Topic: <question>" where the question stands alone, then it should be a tag only.  To that end, if the most popular tag on your question is in your title, it won't prepend that tag in the HTML page title.  [Reference here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71925/145948)

Comment: To elaborate on @Daniel's point, a tag in the title is only deemed worthwhile when it is organic and natural. For example, in the title "Word: How do I use a template to ...", the prefix is not helpful (unless the question is not tagged correctly, but this is not the fix). Whereas in the title "Template behaves differently after upgrading Word 2007 to Word 2010", mentioning the product is quite natural and perhaps even helpful, in addition to the tag. IMHO.