# question <title> tag not updated

Tags: support

This is a really small bug but I tought I'd put it out there.

I couldn't help but notice that after an administrator/moderator changed my stackoverflow question title the website title remained the same:

[Receiving and processing continous packets using UDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659999/receiving-and-processing-continous-packets-using-udp)

Comment: The page title that is currently there is not the same as the one you had. (You'll notice AsyncCallback is not there.) So I'm not sure what your question is about.

Comment: Did you refresh the page already?

Comment: Just FYI, it was not a moderator that changed the title of your question. Anyone with more than 2k reputation can edit any question or answer and anyone with less can suggest an edit.

Answer (score 2):

The new "Receiving and processing continous packets using UDP is not the same as the old "C# AsyncCallback receiving and processing continous packets using UDP".

But I assume you're referring to the "C#" part that you're still seeing for the new title? The most important tag [is added automatically for SEO purposes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions).