# Possibly incorrect display of question title in Browser's Windows Title

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the first tag sometimes in the <title> tag of some questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions)

Ever since https://stackoverflow.com/users/1371188/kamilk added tags to my post https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/18800589 ONLY the Window title of many web browsers I use, in different locales has displayed one of the "encoding":

In FF15.0.1:[image: FF15.0.1]

In IE 8.0.7601.17514:[image: IE 8.0.7601.17514]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Am I missing something? That seems to be the exact title of the question: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DgnXr.png. If you're seeing something different or you think there's a bug, a screenshot of your inbox would be helpful.

Comment: I also fail to see what the problem is. You say the title on that post was changed by user kamilk. But from the revision history it looks like that's not true, kamilk only changed the tags: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13665821/revisions

Comment: @AnnaLear / Ben Lee - Hopefully my second look, subsequent edit, and addition of screenshots will better demonstrate the basic point I was originally trying to get at :)

Comment: @user66001 Ahh, I think I follow now. :) The top tag on the question is only added to the page title. It doesn't actually modify the title of the question itself, so it's not shown in the inbox dropdown or anywhere else, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the "encoding" prefix in the browser's title bar, [this is by-design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions/71925#71925):

> To this end, the tag listed first on a question (sorted by popularity of the tag) will now appear at the start of the page title. Search engines like having keywords in the page title, specifically at the beginning of the page title. If the tag is already in the title, then this new approach won't duplicate the keyword, as you've noticed with several of your links.

Since the [encoding](/questions/tagged/encoding) tag is used more on Stack Overflow than, say, [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), it gets the honor of being featured in the title.

Comment: Hi @Shog9 - Thanks, somehow didn't notice that prior to the tag changes, [tag:cmd] was prefixed.