# How does the system select which tag to show in the search engines?

Tags: support, tags, search, title, seo

One of the sources of visitors to Stack Exchange sites is search engines like Google. When we are shown the results of a question from Stack Exchange sites on Google, we are shown along with a tag. For example, look at below image.

[image: Picture from Google search engine]

In the above picture, the character tag is shown along with character tag. That is the most popular tag tagged with the question.

Now, there is another example from Google as shown below.

[image: Snapshot from Google]

The above question is from Hinduism Stack Exchange where it is shown along with the tag worship. Now, that is not the most popular tag in the question. I have noticed this with other questions too.

The question is how does the system select the tags which are shown with the question in the search engines?

I noticed that these tags accompany in the tabs in the browser too.

[image: pic 3]

So, how does the system select the tags which are to be shown along with the question on search engines like Google?

Comment: That's just the title of the HTML page, as being defined using HTML `<title>` tag. It's not related to search engines, they just take what they see.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two things going on here.

First, a tag which already appears in the question title itself [won't be shown a the first word(s) in the page title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71925/295232); in those cases, the second popular tag will be chosen (unless that is in the title as well, etc.).

That doesn't explain what is going on for [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2989/is-the-ultimate-purpose-of-life-only-to-serve-god), but I guess something else is going on here. *Right now*, the [gods] tag has 311 questions so it is more popular than the [worship] tag (170 questions). However, at the moment of the last edit, three years ago, the reverse was true, and the tags were stored in the order you see them. I suspect that adding another tag, or even a normal edit of the body will change the order and place [gods] as the first one.

Comment: Indeed, the order is not live, it's determined when editing. So when editing old questions, many times we can see the tags order change.