# Why is selection of the first tag automatic?

Tags: discussion, tags, window-title

The tag appearing in the title of a webpage in the browser is the first one that appears below the question.

For example, in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4540934/let-f-be-differentiable-s-t-f0-everywhere-and-nu-f-sharp-mu-is), the first tag appearing below the question is *[real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/real-analysis/info)*; which is also the tag appearing in the title.

The "first tag" is not up to the user's discretion, but it is determined automatically by popularity.

I think that that should not be the case, but the first tag should be in discretion of the user. For example, in the question linked above, I think the tag *[measure-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/measure-theory/info)* is more relevant (because if someone knows real analysis they are quite likely to not be able to answer that question, but if they know measure theory they will almost certainly be able to answer it) (I may be wrong, but that's not the point); so it should be the first tag and the tag in title. But that is not possible.

Why is that? Is there special evidence that the popularity metric works; or it is just as-is from the beginning and no one wants to change that?

Comment: Related: [Should we stop adding the most popular tag to the HTML title on every SE site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127370/295232)

Comment: Maybe you should just retag the question if real analysis is unhelpful. If you're not sure then leave it, a real analysis SME may well retag the question for you.

Comment: This was asked a week or two ago as well, let me see if I can find that. Related Q: [Does the `<title>` prefix from a post tag, that SE renders in post HTML, affect post placement or visibility?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381739/does-the-title-prefix-from-a-post-tag-that-se-renders-in-post-html-affect-po)

Comment: A related feature request on RPG.SE by me, years ago: [Make it possible for certain tags (like game tags) to always appear first](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8366/33569)

Comment: Related: *[How is the tag chosen to prefix the title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153455/how-is-the-tag-chosen-to-prefix-the-title)* and *[How does the system select which tag to show in the search engines?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303785/how-does-the-system-select-which-tag-to-show-in-the-search-engines)*

Comment: This is a feature request, not a discussion. The tags and title here are misleading, but the body contains clear cut proof: "I think that that should not be the case, but the first tag should be in discretion of the user". This is purely a feature request.

Comment: That's the author's choice, they can ask why or they can ask for change, even both, it's up to them.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I am not saying "I *want* this to exist". Its more on the lines of "I think this should exist. why doesn't it exist yet". Anyway the question's been closed, so its futile

Comment: "I think this should exist" implies you want it, which means on a meta site, it's a feature request.

Comment: The voting on a "discussion" question would be based on (amongst other reasons): is it worth discussing, has it been discussed recently, is the question well written, etc. --- As a feature request the voting would usually be based on whether people wanted the change or thought that the proposed improvement was more important than fixing something else. --- If the change was unwanted that would result in a negative score, instead of the +3 it currently holds.

Answer (score -4):

> "... the first tag should be in discretion of the user.".

It is, you are free to remove any tag (except red tags), and a minimum of one tag is necessary, here at MSE there are [mandatory tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47640/282094) which must be included first, but they can be chosen by the author too.

The writer of the question initially decides on the title, afterwards tags are automatically suggested and added tags are ordered by popularity. Where there are mandatory tags they are first, but those are still chosen by the editor.

The algorithm behind chosing tags automatically requires over 20K questions in order to provide good results.

There is required to be a sufficient number of questions and for their to be a match before a tag is suggested.

The *best* tag may not always be suggested but the author (and subsequent editors) are free to remove incorrect tags and manually replace them with better choices.

> "... I think the tag `measure-theory` is more relevant ... so it should be the first tag and the tag in title. But that is not possible.

The asker of the question and subsequent editors decide on the title and tags, persons with enough reputation can create new tags

> Why is that? Is there special evidence that the popularity metric works; or it is just as-is from the beginning and no one wants to change that?

The algorithm needs enough example questions to provide the best results, it's not so much a "popularity metric" as it is a requirement to have sufficient examples.

See also:

- ["On which sites are suggested tags currently enabled?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359591/282094)
- ["Automatically remove tags that are at the beginning of titles"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132829/282094)
- ["Can we prevent titles with an unnecessary tag in them?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103563/282094)

A site needs to have enough questions to have a sufficient number of eligible tags. On the [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions) site, with the 2nd most number of questions, 1,538,785 / 20K = 77 tags, there's an approximately 1/4000 chance of having an eligible tag; assuming that on average you chose a popular tag.

The ordering of tags and requests to be able to set the order has been thoroughly discussed on Stack Overflow's meta:

- ["Force order of tags"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367100/3648282)
- ["In what order do tags appear on a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253271/3648282)
- ["Does the order of tags matter when tagging a question? [duplicate]"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355883/does-the-order-of-tags-matter-when-tagging-a-question#comment509607_355884)
- ["Should the ability to order tags manually be included for SEO purposes?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411976/3648282)
- ["Please do not sort the tags by question count"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273126/3648282)

With a 1 in 4000 chance of the tag being eligible on the second place site the usefulness of changing this question to a feature request (as has been suggested by two people) remains in doubt and leaves this question mainly applicable to only one site.

Comment: Your answer seems to assume that if somebody doesn't want a tag to be first then this means that the tag is irrelevant for the question and should be removed altogether. However, looking at the current question for example (ignoring the `discussion` tag for now), both `tags` and `title` are relevant but `tags` is arguably more important for the question and should therefore be "first". If `title` was removed to make that happen then useful information would be lost.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. I don't have a new question, I commented on your answer to whosit's question. Their question was "I want to choose the first tag" and your answer, as I read it, was "you can, just remove all other tags and the remaining one will be first". While technically true, I don't think that is a good solution, because it would be better if there was a way (which currently is not possible) to choose the order _and_ keep all relevant tags.

Comment: I know the tags are chosen by the OP or later editors, but they didn't choose the _order_ of the tags as they appear below the question and in question lists. So here the user selected `discussion` `tags` `title`, but maybe they preferred to show them as `tags` `discussion` `title` or `discussion` `title` `tags`. This meta question (and my comments above) is about the order, not the choice of the tags as such.

Comment: I am not asking something different - I am not asking anything at all, I am just trying to clarify the OP. They asked, as you quoted, "the first tag should be in discretion of the user". This means "choose the order of tags". Your answer is mainly about tags being suggested by the system automatically, but this is not what OPs question is about.