# Need tag abbreviation expansion/synonyms for SEO purposes

Tags: feature-request, tags, seo

On RPG.SE we have a significant SEO problem stemming from our use of (semi-) standard abbreviations for RPG names in tags.  This is exacerbated by tags not taking special characters and having a 25 character limit.

In the normal SEs, this isn't so much of a problem because [perl], [python], even [windows-server-2008] are short and you can just use them in the tag.

However, common game names in the RPG world are "Dungeons & Dragons Fourth Edition", "Dungeons & Dragons Essentials", "Mutants & Masterminds Second Edition", and similar.  Normally, we'd abbreviate those things like "D&D 4e" but you can't, you have to do things like [dnd-4e] and the resulting tags are, we think, resulting in poor SEO.

You can see one person's analysis of the search results for our SE from a variety of combinations here: [Proposed tag synonyms for [dnd4.0]](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/669/proposed-tag-synonyms)
We're only at 42% search engine referrals.

So what do we use?
To drill into the D&D 4e example (which is by no means the only place we have this problem, but it is illustrative) [dnd4.0] was bad because there was no implicit space between dnd and 4.0.
[dnd-4.0] is somewhat better.  But the dnd isn't quite "D&D".  And what if they are searching on "Dungeons & Dragons?"  Do we tag everything multiple times for SEO reasons?
[dungeons-and-dragons-4e] might be better, but these forms start going over the 25 character tag limit.  [dungeons-and-dragons-essentials] isn't possible. And again, what about searches on "D&D" now? We can NOT have it be the community's job to be retagging every single post with multiple tags to make it more SEO friendly.

Things that could help this a little.

2. Allow special characters (& especially) in tags.  [d&d-4e] would help.
3. Let the tag field be a bit bigger, so things like [dungeons-and-dragons-essentials] fit.  40 characters maybe.
4. Give us some guidance on what helps/doesn't help/works/doesn't work. We tried to get that in [How do tags influence Stack Exchange's SEO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70060/how-do-tags-influence-stack-exchanges-seo) to no avail. We have been unable to get any guidance when we ask if we should be tagging a question, for example, [dnd-4e] and also [dungeons-and-dragons] in an attempt to get SEO? Will searches for D&D just pass us by?

The real solution.
More advanced functionality where synonyms, perhaps drawn from the tag wiki, are inserted for SEO purposes.  Let's say we tag with "[dnd4]" for brevity.  If there were a way to configure "hey, that should map to 'D&D 4e' and 'Dungeons & Dragons Fourth Edition' in the tag wikis or synonym screens, and then SE should insert those expanded values into the page (optionally, just for search engines).

Comment: The "real solution" as described in the question would certainly solve the issues in http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1411/how-should-we-improve-character-optimization-question-tagging

Comment: For SEO, the *tags* really shouldn't matter much if the *titles* are descriptive... But I'm guessing no one relishes the thought of changing titles to "Optimizing a Dungeons & Dragons 3.5 Edition Monk" / "Do cover providing powers provide cover from adjacent melee attacks in Dungeons & Dragons Fourth Edition?" / etc.

Comment: Correct, the purpose of tags is so people don't have to do that; they can ask more terse questions tagged so that the domain is clearly defined.

Comment: Do keep in mind that modern search engines perform acronym expansion automatically under certain circumstances.  Google currently recognizes "4e" as "4th Edition" in the context of D&D... but oddly doesn't expand D&D to "Dungeons & Dragons," while it autocorrects "DnD" to "D&D".

Comment: Just to say it out loud we still suffer from this issue more than 10 years later, see the brand new meta Q on our site complaining about our poor D&D by version SEO: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11357/why-does-stackexchange-return-only-posts-for-dnd5e-when-explicitly-googling-for

Comment: At least part of this FR was handled, partially. [Back in 2017, the limit for tag names was increased to 35 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/271271) ([or 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306500/271271)), which isn't quite the 40 which you requested, but should notably help.