# Update "Create Tags" documentation to be accurate about permissible tag lengths

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-creation, privileges-page

[/help/privileges/create-tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) reads as follows:

> Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created. When creating your new tag, bear in mind that tags ...
>
> - must be shorter than 25 characters
> - must use the character set `a-z` `0-9` `+` `#` `-` `.`

This is false - tags must be **at most** 25 characters in length (i.e. 25-character tags *are* permitted).

(This is also a doc bug at least [on ja.SO](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags), where it reads 「25 文字未満」, which means "shorter than 25 characters".)

Comment: This is now done on the sites where the Help Center is in English.

Answer (score 3):

This has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (and reflects the [change of the character limit to 35](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/295232)); the page now reads

> Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created. When creating your new tag, bear in mind that tags ...
>
> - must be no longer than 35 characters
> - must use the character set `a-z` `0-9` `+` `#` `-` `.`

This was changed somewhere between [May 2016](http://web.archive.org/web/20160513223027/https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) and (according to the comment on the question) August 2016.