# Ask question button is partially obscured on long-named-tag page

Tags: bug, tags, design, russian-stackoverflow

After [increasing maximum tag length to 35 symbols](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/339911) the <kbd>Ask Question</kbd> button looks partially obscured on tag page. E.g. for tag ["функциональное-программирование"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/) on Stack Overflow in Russian:

> [image: Ask button]

Comment: @Close/down-voter: while observed on SO-in-Russian, this problem is reasonably likely to be observable on any SE website, given character limit for tags is network-wide - as such it's absolutely not site-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [looks fixed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/) now:

> [image: функциональное-программирование]