# Top viewed questions by tag within a timeframe

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

How can I use the data explorer to fetch the top viewed questions within a certain tag within some time frame on Stack Overflow?

For example, the top viewed questions tagged [Android] in the last 6 months.

**[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/886221/most-viewed-questions-in-tag)** is a query that fetches top viewed questions by tag, but still, need some help.

**Update**

@Arulkumar answer is helpful but it does not fulfill the need. His answer fetches questions asked in that time frame.

But I want to get most viewed questions within the time frame with a certain tag.

Comment: Which site? SEDE generally needs to be separated by site. Several sites have questions about Android. Heck, there's an entire site about it, [android.se].

Comment: In Stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

You can add the Period in months as integer and handle with [`DATEADD`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in the WHERE clause as `(Q.CreationDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -@Period, GETUTCDATE()) AND GETUTCDATE())`.

[Query in SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/887885)

```
DECLARE @Tag VARCHAR(35) = '##Tag##'
DECLARE @Period INT = '##Period##'

SELECT TOP 50 Q.Id AS [Post Link], 
    Q.Tags, Q.AnswerCount, Q.ViewCount
FROM Posts AS Q
INNER JOIN PostTags AS P ON P.PostId = Q.Id
INNER JOIN Tags AS T ON T.Id = P.TagId
WHERE T.TagName = @Tag AND
      (Q.CreationDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -@Period, GETUTCDATE()) AND GETUTCDATE())
ORDER BY Q.ViewCount DESC
```

Comment: It is gonna be my favorite query :), thank you so much.

Comment: How can I save query to my favorites?

Comment: Once you login the data.stackexchange.com, you can  easily favorite this query to your account

Comment: Note that tagnames can now be up to [35 chars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/158100)

Comment: Hi, today I noticed this query is showing only questions asked from time frame I entered. But my need is to fetch from all questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Khemraj That was your requirement _the top viewed questions tagged [android] in the last 6 months._. If you are need to find irrespective of the time frame, remove the date range check from the _WHERE_ clause in the query

Comment: Your answer is very useful for me, but my need was questions that were viewed the most in last 6 months. You got me bro? You also filtered questions asked in last 6 month.

Comment: @Khemraj that data isn't in the public SEDE instance. The history of viewcount isn't available.

Comment: Okay @rene , thanks for your time. I was just wondering to see the topics trending on Stackoverflow.