# Badge icons on the 'top tags' section of the user profile are moved into new lines

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, tag-badges

[image]

The picture is from [this profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/2451/qmechanic), though it appears for almost everyone with tag badges for things on that third row of tags: the badge itself is moved onto the next line when the tag name is long. This looks kind of awkward: there appears to be a lot of space remaining to the right of the tag itself.

If it's too difficult to move that circle up to that spare space, can we at least split the tag to span neatly over both lines of that region? Most long tags are multiple words long, so maybe it'd be possible to split it along one of the hyphens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically, there's plenty of space here - unless you have extremely high scores in some of [the longest tags possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags/299490#299490), there's no reason to be stingy.

So I just added a `white-space: nowrap` style here; this'll keep both the tag and the associated badge indicator from wrapping, forcing the entire layout to be wider if necessary.