# Tag length increase from 25 to 35 characters was not actually done here on MSE

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, meta, character-limit

The tag character limit was [supposedly increased from 25 to 35 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/377214) "on all sites". However, here on MSE, the tag length increase was not actually implemented.

As would be expected, you get an error message when you try to create a tag that is longer than 35 characters:

[image: 38 character tag error message]

That example was 38 characters; you might be thinking that that error message is just a typo. But it's not:

[image: 29 characters not permitted on MSE]

This one is a mere 29 characters.

Also, the "How to Tag" box on the right still also says "25 characters":

[image: "up to a maximum of 25 characters"]

Is it intentional that the tag length limit hike was not supposed to be implemented on MSE, or is this a bug?

Comment: MSE was always special. ;)

Comment: I totally want a gold badge for [tag:amy-rose-is-not-my-girlfriend] ...

Comment: @rene You want a Chaos Emerald for that? Behold, the power of the Chaos Emeralds!

Comment: My precious Chaos Emerald. You are all so beautiful. Your mysterious brilliance...

Comment: By the way, for those of you reading the above comment, that was said by the *actual* Rouge the Bat in a *Sonic the Hedgehog* game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were site-specific overrides on MSE, MSO and Stack Apps... These predated the existence of logging for such changes, so I've no idea *why* they were customized, but there's no obvious need for them at present so I've reverted them to the network default (35 characters).

Comment: Luckily Area 51 has no tags.