# Increase the tag search input box length according to maximum allowed tag length

Tags: feature-request, tags, design, tag-search

Currently the tag search input box on the [tag page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) is too short:

> [image: MSE tag]

I suggest to increase the size of this input according to [maximum allowed tag length](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306500/339911). There is a lot of horizontal space to do this without a problem. In case of narrow screen size the resize policy could use all available space to prevent obscuring the tab controls on the page.

My feature-request is mainly inspired by too long text placeholder for input on [ruSO tag page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags):

> [image: ruSO tag]